# Can I declare credentials only once for a REST API?

Tags: powerquery, powerbi

I am using Power Query within Power BI Designer to query a REST API. The first request is to:
http://domain/httpAuth/app/rest/server
which returns:

```
<server>
<builds href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds"/>
</server>
```

From there I use Power Query to query http://domain/httpAuth/app/rest/builds in order to get a list of builds and then iterate over the list of builds, calling each one in turn. The format of the URL for each build is:
http://domain/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:buildId

The problem is I'm getting prompted to enter credentials for every single request. This is tedious and unworkable (we have a lot of builds).
Is there a way to define the credentials once for (say) stub http://domain/httpAuth/app/rest and have every resource under that stub use the same credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no direct way to do this for HTTP sources. A workaround for now is to connect to the root source first (http://domain/httpAuth/app/rest/builds or just http://domain/) and set the credentials there.

If you trust all of the data sources you are connecting to, you can also disable the firewall by going to the Workbook Settings dialog and selecting the Ignore option for Fast Combine.

EDIT: Sorry, I misread the question. In the case of credentials, connect to the root source first and set the credential there. This credential should be used for the remaining URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set an Authorization Header and set it with your request.

(Apologies for for the Wiki link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply. How would I do that in Power BI Designer though?

Comment: I've never used Power BI designer however if its using Basic authoriszation. You should only have to specify the parameters in the request.
How are you calling the REST url? Curl? Java? etc.

Comment: Ah, the question is definitely pertinent to Power BI Designer (that is the tool being used as opposed to curl etc..) so if you've never used that I suspect you won't be able to help here. Power BI Designer does allow you to specify creds of course, and for different auth mechanisms. From a high-level though the question is basically "In Power BI Designer how do I define creds once and use them in multiple requests?" Thx anyway.